# groupby: trying to group by country and list top 10 varieties per country along with avg price and avg points

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to generate a dataframe which is grouped by country and lists top 10 varieties of wine in each country along with their average price and points.

I have successfully grouped by country and wine and generated average values of price and points.
I can generate top 10 varieties in each country by using value_counts().nlargesst(10) but I can't get rid of the remaining in the initial group by with the averages

```
countryGroup = df.groupby(['country', 'variety'])['price','points'].mean().round(2).rename(columns = {'price':'AvgPrice','points':'AvgPoints'})
countryVariety = df.groupby('country')['variety']
countryVariety = countryVariety.apply(lambda x:x.value_counts().nlargest(10))
```

[data link](https://www.kaggle.com/zynicide/wine-reviews#winemag-data_first150k.csv)

[image]

actual result is a list of top 10 varieties in each country.
but what I need along with this is the average price and points

Comment: this is my first question. just getting a hang of this

Comment: can you add some sample data and expected output?

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: edit your question and then add those details

Answer (score 2):

Here's some sample data. For these problems, where a large quantity of data is required, it's useful to generate random test data, which can be done in a few lines:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import string

np.random.seed(123)
n = 1000
df = pd.DataFrame({'country': np.random.choice(list('AB'), n),
                   'variety': np.random.choice(list(string.ascii_lowercase), n),
                   'price':  np.random.normal(100, 10, n),
                   'points': np.random.choice(100, n)})
```

One way to solve this is to `groupby` twice. The first allows us to calculate the quantities for each country-variety group. The second keeps the top 10 per country (based on size) with `.sort_values` + `tail`

```
df_agg = (df.groupby(['country', 'variety']).agg({'variety': 'size', 'price': 'mean', 'points': 'mean'})
            .rename(columns={'variety': 'size'}))
df_agg = df_agg.sort_values('size').groupby(level=0).tail(10).sort_index()
```

#### Output:

```
                 size       price     points
country variety                             
A       c          19   98.606563  45.842105
        e          19  102.264391  48.894737
        l          23   96.469739  52.913043
        n          27   99.532544  55.740741
        p          20   98.298753  49.700000
        q          21   98.660938  60.666667
        u          26  101.330755  63.615385
        x          20  102.540790  48.550000
        y          23   99.553557  49.869565
        z          27   99.968973  44.259259
B       b          25   99.375984  56.360000
        c          22  100.632402  56.181818
        e          25   99.476491  49.520000
        k          22   96.991041  40.090909
        p          24   99.802004  51.333333
        q          26   99.022372  53.884615
        u          22  103.063360  49.090909
        v          24  101.907610  53.250000
        x          22   94.607472  49.227273
        z          23   98.984382  44.739130
```

Comment: HI, thanks that worked. Sorry for a poor question quality. Can you explain a bit more how this worked ? I am failrly new to pandas

Comment: Sure. This is very similar to what you had attempted, the only difference is that I also calculate the `size` of each country-variety group (which will tell you how many times that variety appeared in that country). `.agg` allows different functions to be applied to each column. Then you can sort based on the size (largest sizes are at the bottom). Next you `groupby(level=0)` which is the country level of the index and `.tail(10)` chooses the last 10 rows within each country. Since we previously sorted, these will be the rows with the 10 most occurring wines within each country.

Comment: makes sense. thank you very much its good to know I was thinking in the right direction

Comment: how do I use round() on mean?

Comment: @AshutoshMishra You can just call `.round(2) at the very end. It wont affect `size` since it's an integer.